# What's the probability of multiple lottery draws containing exactly one same number?

Tags: probability, combinations

Let's say there is a lottery of N numbers, where M numbers are drawn each time.

How do I calculate probability of exactly one number drawn twice in X draws?
(matching between each of the draws made, not matching against my single ticket)

(So let's say I draw 4 times 6 numbers of 49 - then I am interested in probability that from 24 numbers drawn I get one number drawn exactly twice, while rest - 22 - being unique)

Additionally what would be formula for probability that all numbers are unique?

Thanks for all suggestions and explanations.

Comment: Your title question and post question are different. Also, does order matter?

Comment: Hi Tiwa. Sorry, if I should take all details in title question, it would be too long. To your question - order is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following approach will work:

If there is exactly one duplicated number, it must have been drawn on days $i$ and $j$ for some $(i,j)\in\{(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)\}$. Count the number of ways this can happen for each $(i,j)$ separately, and use these counts to find the corresponding probabilities $p_{(i,j)}$. The probability you seek will be the sum of these $p_{(i,j)}$, because they represent exclusive and exhaustive possibilities for the one-duplicate event.

For example, let’s count the number of draws that yield one duplicate, drawn on days $2$ and $3$. There are $49\choose6$ possible draws for the first day. On day $2$, there are $43\choose6$ for each possible day-$1$ draw (so ${49\choose6}\cdot{43\choose6}$ possible ways to obtain no duplicate through day $2$). On day three, there are $49-12=37$ unchosen numbers, from which $5$ are picked, along with one of the $6$ numbers chosen on day $2$, so ${37\choose5}\cdot{6\choose1}$ possibilities. Finally, on day $4$, six of the $49-6-6-5=32$ unchosen numbers are drawn. Since there are ${49\choose6}^4$ ways the draws could have taken place with no restriction, the probability for $(i,j)=(2,3)$ is $$p_{(2,3)}=\frac{{49\choose6}\cdot{43\choose6}\cdot{37\choose5}\cdot{6\choose1}\cdot{32\choose6}}{{49\choose6}^4}$$.

There may be a way to avoid the separate calculations, but I don’t see an obvious one.

Comment: You should multiply by $4 \choose 2$ for the ways to choose the two days with a match to get the final answer.

Comment: Thanks, Steve and @Ross-Millikan. I seem to struggle with this one. Maybe I am doing something wrong, but let's suppose, that Steve provided a correct solution for two same figures selected on day 2 and 3. Applying the same logic to create calculation for match on days 2 and 4 however, produces a different result while I would say that probability should be the same. Thoughts?

Comment: My mistake ... I got it. $p_{(2,4)}=\frac{{49\choose6}\cdot{43\choose6}\cdot{37\choose6}\cdot{31\choose5}\cdot{6\choose1}}{{49\choose6}^4}$ produces the same result. Thank you both. And as suggested, additional multiplying will do the job. Hope I'll figure formula with variables ...

Comment: As Ross hints at in his comment, I overlooked the simple fact that the probability of a single duplicated number appearing on days $i$ and $j$ is independent of $i$ and $j$, so the six ($4\choose2$) “separate calculations” I mentioned must all yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

By "same number" you mean the same six digit number, right?  And "six numbers of 49" means that there are 49 possible numbers to be drawn?  If so then the chance of getting any one number is 1/49.  The probability of getting the same number twice is the binomial probability $\begin{pmatrix}6 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}(1/49)^2(48/49)^4= 15\frac{48^4}{49^6}$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 6-digit number. Could you expand on this? Also, why wouldn't it be $\frac{\binom{MX}2}{(_NP_M)^X}$? $(_NP_M)^X$ possible drawing combinations, and $MX$ numbers from which $2$ are the same?

Comment: Lottery has 49 balls numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 47, 48, 49. Each day they draw 6 unique balls (but each day, you start again with 49 balls to draw). In 4 days (4 draws of 6 balls), what is the chance that 1 ball will be drawn twice, but all other drawn balls drawn just once? Hope I clarified.

Answer (score 0):

For all the numbers unique, you can have any draw the first time.  The second you have to select from the unused $43$ numbers, so there are $43 \choose 6$ ways.  The third you have $37$ available and choose $6$, then you have $33$, so the chance is $$\frac {{43 \choose 6}{37 \choose 6}{33 \choose 6}}{{49 \choose 6}^3}=\frac{246240567131}{42894972773037} \approx 0.00574$$ per [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(43%20choose%206)(37%20choose%206)(33%20choose%206)%2F(49%20choose%206)%5E3)

Comment: Thanks, @Ross-Millikan. Appreciate it. This greatly explains! Could you suggest any way to create formula using these variables? n = count of numbers/balls in lottery m = count of drawn balls in one day x = number of days? I'm interested in some input-output experimenting using excel.

Comment: (Thanks for answering the part of the question I overlooked!)

Comment: Excel may not easily handle these large numbers, but a general formula for the all-distinct part of the question Ross answered here is $$\frac{\displaystyle\prod_{d=1}^{x-1}{n-dm\choose m}}{{n\choose m}^{x-1}}.$$

Note that if $d$ and/or $m$ are large enough that the total number of balls drawn exceeds the number of distinct balls, the probability will be zero; the numerator in this formula will contain a zero factor (a binomial coefficient of the form $N\choose M$ with $M>N$).